# flutter Build Error - Error when running on virtual mobile device

Tags: flutter, android-studio, build

When building in a mobile environment, an error occurs.
Google Chrome does it right. However, when running on Pixel 4 api 30 (mobile), an error occurs.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:parseDebugLocalResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider_android:androidApis'.
   > Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-31\android.jar.
         > C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-31\android.jar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

jdk version
[image]

app build.gralde

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
```

build.gralde

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**I updated Android Studio to the latest version**.

**I installed jdk and added sdk 11.**

**I have created a project in a new folder.**

I've been thinking about this door for two days, but I couldn't solve it.

If you have a problem with my questioning method or code, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this solution**

in build.gradle **<project-file/android/app/build.gradle>** (app level)

```
compileSdkVersion 31
```

and

```
   defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 31
           ...        
  }
```

in build.gradle **<project-file/android/build.gradle>** (project level) :

```
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1'
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but where are the app level and project level build.gradle?

Comment: What should I do if I change targetSdkVersion 28 and Google asks for app target 31 or higher?>

Comment: okay will edit the answer to show you the location of this files

Comment: you can make targetSdkVersion 31

Comment: If you do it the way you told you, you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. but i fix it.
just delete android sdk 31 and reinstall it.